# How to pass a list of functions in parameters ? (UnityAction[])

Tags: c#, function, unity-game-engine, parameters

I have a little problem with how to call my function.

Before, I only needed one parameters and i wrote the function like that (i absolutely need to call it like that) :

```
public void SetDialogs(UnityAction pFunctionClic){blablabla};
SetDialogs(() => MyClicFunction());
```

Now, i need to have multiple function in the parameters. So, i set my SetDialogs function like this :

```
public void SetDialogs(UnityAction[] pFunctionClic){blablabla};
```

Now, the problem is that i don't know what to write when i call my function. 
Obviously

```
SetDialogs(() => [MyClicFunction()]);
```

doesn't work.

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used Unity before, but judging by what you're doing, you can pass an array of UnityAction as such:

```cs
SetDialogs(new UnityAction[] {
    () => MyClickFunction(),
    () => SomeOtherStuff(),
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `params` array parameter. A `params` parameter must always be the last (or the only one) in the parameter list

```
public void SetDialogs(params UnityAction[] pFunctionClic){ ... };
```

Now you can pass it with as many `UnityAction` parameters as you need.

```
SetDialogs(() => MyClicFunction());
SetDialogs(() => MyClicFunction1(), () => MyClicFunction2());
SetDialogs(() => MyClicFunction1(), () => MyClicFunction2(), () => MyClicFunction3());
```

Inside the method you always see an array. When calling the method you don't need to pass it an array (C# converts the parameters to an array automatically); however, you can:

```
var unityActions = new UnityAction[] {
    () => MyClicFunction1(),
    () => MyClicFunction2(),
    () => MyClicFunction3()
};
SetDialogs(unityActions);
```